# Need to change php SoapClient for Vecozo requests. They indicated to change url but they don't give a new wsdl

Tags: php, soap-client

A while ago I implemented a Soap connection with the Dutch Vecozo company retrieving insurance information for Dutch citizens. Now Vecozo has announced to migrate their server to an Azure environment and therefore I need to change the URLs. My SoapClient is constructed with their supplied wsdl which they supplied years back. However they did not supply a new wsdl file for the new Azure server. They just indicated that the old URL need to be changed to https://api.vecozo.nl/cov/vz801802/v1/soap11

To implement this I added the location and uri option parameters. Also I added __setLocation. However since the connection was also working before, and still after this change, how do I know it actually goes to the new Azure server (they have them both parallel running until Jan 2021)? Did I implement the URL correctly? Any suggestions how to do this otherwise?

```
 $soap_options = array('local_cert'=>$certFile, 
                        'trace'=>1, 
                        'location' => "https://api.vecozo.nl/cov/vz801802/v1/soap11",
                        'uri'      => "https://api.vecozo.nl/cov/vz801802/v1/soap11",
                        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_incoming_flat, $soap_options);
 
// new url 2021
$client->__setLocation('https://api.vecozo.nl/cov/vz801802/v1/soap11');
```

Comment: Is there a staging/test server you can use to run some non-mocked integration tests?

Comment: They indeed have a test enviroment but will also not give info if it's the new Azure enviroment

Answer (score 0):

If I examine my soap header before it was;

```
POST /v1/VZ801802.svc/soap11 HTTP/1.1
Host: covwebservice.vecozo.nl
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.16
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.vecozo.nl/VZ801802/v1/Controleer"
Content-Length: 897
```

After the location change it became;

```
POST /cov/vz801802/v1/soap11 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.vecozo.nl
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.16
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.vecozo.nl/VZ801802/v1/Controleer"
Content-Length: 897
```

I think this is what Vecozo means with changing the url. The Host and POST changed..